# How to uninstall Java 1.8 under OS X 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: macos, java, oracle

There are a few answers on old questions about the same issue under Lion / Mountain Lion. Now with Java 1.8 and OS X 10.10 I wonder if anything has changed? Would be great to have exact removal steps.

It really is asked too much, for Oracle to provide a proper uninstaller?

Answer (score 13):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jre.html#A1096890 says

> To uninstall the JRE, you must have Administrator privileges and execute the remove commands either as root or by using the sudo(8) tool.
>
> Remove one directory and one file (a symlink), as follows:
>
> - Navigate to `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` and remove the `JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` directory.
> - Navigate to `/Library/PreferencePanes` and remove `JavaControlPanel.prefpane`.
>
> Do not attempt to uninstall Java by removing the Java tools from `/usr/bin`. This directory is part of the system software and any changes will be reset by Apple the next time you perform an update of the OS

Done that. Looking good. I still think it's bad intentions behind not offering an uninstaller. Glad this is off my system.

Commands for the ‘Terminal’ly-inclined:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
```

Comment: Hmm. When I view the JavaAppletPlugin.plugin, I see that it is an alias. The original is located at: /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/   How does deleting the alias remove Java? Is it safe to delete that whole /System/Library/Java directory? Thanks

Comment: Just delete the alias - never delete anything from /System/* if you don't know what you'r doing.

Answer (score 2):

An uninstaller might be nice, but you literally have to drag one file to the trash. Doesn't seem too difficult.

Per [Java.com](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml):

> To uninstall Java, you must have Administrator privileges.
>
> 1. Click on the Finder icon located in your dock
> 2. Click on Applications tab on the sidebar
> 3. In the Search box enter JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
> 4. This will find the JavaAppletPlugin.plugin file
> 5. Right click on JavaAppletPlugin.plugin and select Move to Trash

Comment: That only uninstalls the web plugin not the JDK or old style JRE

Answer (score 0):

Just run these commands

```
 sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/*

 sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/Java*

 sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/Java*
```